# Close chrome tabs by domain

Tags: google-chrome

I need an a way to close all open Chrome tabs from a given domain list.

For example, I got home, opened a few social networks, news sites, or whatever. The computer hibernated at some point and next morning I want to go back to 'productive' mode. Is there any scriptable way to close all chrome tabs that are browsing any page under a given list of domain names?

Using Chrome for Windows, latest version. Adding a chrome extension or some guidance on how to write a new extension is acceptable if there is no other way.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an extension that close all tabs whose URLs contain "duckduckgo.com/?q=" or "google.com/search":

[Close Search Tabs](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/close-search-tabs/ecaalgnjbpjhbjlhbaiodjkmkbjfjfpb/related?hl=en), by Tai Groot (tai@taigrr.com):

```
function announce_close(){
    console.log("closing all search tabs")
    chrome.tabs.query({}, function(tabs) {
        var closeable=[];
        for (var i=0; i<tabs.length; ++i) {
            console.log(tabs[i]);
            if(tabs[i].url.includes("google.com/search?")) {    
                closeable.push(tabs[i].id)
            } else if(tabs[i].url.includes("duckduckgo.com/?q=")){
                closeable.push(tabs[i].id)
            }
        }
        chrome.tabs.remove(closeable);
    });
}
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab){announce_close()});
```

Code license:

```
Copyright (C) 2019-2021 by Tai Groot <tai@taigrr.com>

Permission to use, copy, modify, and/or distribute this software for any
purpose with or without fee is hereby granted.

THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS" AND THE AUTHOR DISCLAIMS ALL WARRANTIES
WITH REGARD TO THIS SOFTWARE INCLUDING ALL IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF
MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHOR BE LIABLE FOR
ANY SPECIAL, DIRECT, INDIRECT, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES OR ANY DAMAGES
WHATSOEVER RESULTING FROM LOSS OF USE, DATA OR PROFITS, WHETHER IN AN
ACTION OF CONTRACT, NEGLIGENCE OR OTHER TORTIOUS ACTION, ARISING OUT OF
OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE USE OR PERFORMANCE OF THIS SOFTWARE.
```